# Why does jquery fancybox sometimes generate garbage url requests to my server?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am noticing some strange requests on my server, and I'm pretty sure they are generated by the jquery fancybox plugin. The requests look like this:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/,d.href);d.aspectRatio=!0;break;case"
Started GET "/javascripts/)&&d.html(b)%7Delse%7Bd=c("
Started GET "/javascripts/%7Bhref%7D"
```

I point the finger at fancybox, because when I grep my source code for those strange strings, I always find them somewhere inside jquery.fancybox.pack.js

Has anyone else see this? Is this a known bug? Am I doing it wrong?
I am succesfully using fancybox features, although these errors make me think some of my users are not so fortunate. Could it be a browser issue, with users on older (incompatible) browsers?

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that you are missing a quote in your own urls. Try to `escape()` any param querystrings on your urls. Especially if you are using single or double quotes somewhere as the params value.